# SQL - how to round to 2 decimal places

Tags: sql, vb.net, select, decimal, rounding

I have a query as below

```
Dim DoneAvgCont As New OleDbCommand("select avg(diffpay) ,conrtname from metersdone",con)
Dim DoneAvgContdb As New OleDbDataAdapter(DoneAvgCont)
    Dim DoneAvgContDt As New DataTable
```

the result of avg(diffpay) column is like 55.2516494664 and I want to round to 55.25

I use visual basic.net 2015 and I get my from access

Comment: That is the actual value. You would only need to round it up when displaying it, which should be a different part of the code.

Comment: Do you need to round the actual value, or simply display it with 2 decimals?

Comment: thank all for fast reply >>> i do it like @Damirchi answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your query in first line like this

```
Dim DoneAvgCont As New OleDbCommand("select round(avg(diffpay),2) ,conrtname from metersdone",con)
```

Comment: It would be nice to accept Damirchi's answer since it is the solution for you.

Comment: really i cant ...i have to get 15 reputation